# How to model an uncertain (or erroneous) truncation effect on a random variable?

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, inference, uncertainty, truncation

Let $ V_a $ be a random variable which is truncated at a value $v_c$. Therefore, the updated density function of truncated $V_a$ is given by,
$$ f(v_a| V_a\leq v_c) = \frac{g(v_a)}{F(v_c)}$$
where $g(v_a) = f(v_a)$ for all $v_a \leq v_c$ and $g(x) = 0$ everywhere else, and $F(\cdot)$ is the cumulative distribution function.

This formulation assumes perfect truncation at $v_c$. But what if, the truncation at $v_c$ is only successful with a probability $p$?

Is there any theoretical framework that can help me get the truncation distribution accounting for this uncertainty?

Comment: I think I may have solved my own question.

If the success of the truncation process is given by a probability $p$, then $g(v_a)=f(v_a)~p$ for all $v_a≤v_c$ and $g(v_a)=f(v_a)~(1-p)$ everywhere else.

Is it?

Comment: No, this sounds like the wrong answer: if the rv is truncated with probability $p$ and un-truncated otherwise, the density is a mixture between the truncated and the untruncated versions.

Comment: @Xi'an, how would that mixture look mathematically? Are there any keywords that I can Google to figure this out?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixture_distribution